# Is there a budget version of Collected Company for this Modern elf deck?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I wanted to buy a Modern deck (a competitive one) for a private tournament which will be in a nearest future. I'm bored with the ones I already have so I wanted to build a new one... I'm currently working on an elf deck and I need some budget alternative to a [Collected Company](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCollected%20Company%5d) if there are any of those... I can afford to add only 2 Collected Companies at this moment but I think that something more consistent as a 4 of will be better. Any suggestions?

My deck also contains:

- 4 x [Arbor Elf](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bArbor%20Elf%5d)
- 4 x [Elvish Mystic](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bElvish%20Mystic%5d)
- 2 x [Joraga Warcaller](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bJoraga%20Warcaller%5d)
- 4 x [Elvish Archdruid](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bElvish%20Archdruid%5d)
- 4 x [Imperious Perfect](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bImperious%20Perfect%5d)
- 2 x [Ezuri, Renegade Leader](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEzuri%2c%20Renegade%20Leader%5d)
- 4 x [Elvish Clancaller](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bElvish%20Clancaller%5d)

That's what I came up with for now. I'm thinking of having 16-17 lands here and I need any suggestions about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there isn't.

Collected Company is one hell of a card. It's 1) instant speed, 2) card advantage, 3) usually mana advantage and 4) half a tutor. CoCo (as it's often called) is the best card in the deck, and there's nothing that can compare.

You could potentially run [Chord of Calling](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bChord%20of%20Calling%5d), but it's significantly worse because convoke works really badly with mana creatures which you have a lot of, and besides Chord of Calling is also an expensive card. Otherwise there is [Lead the Stampede](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLead%20the%20Stampede%5d) which will draw you cards, but does not put them into play; and [Eldritch Evolution](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bEldritch%20Evolution%5d) which will tutor a relevant card, but is not nearly as efficient (and isn't cheap either).

If you don't have 4 copies of Collected Company, you should still run as many copies as you can.